# Expieriences Plesk upgrade from 12.0.18 to 12.5.30?

Tags: plesk

I have two bare metal servers running **Plesk 12.0.18 Update #75**.

I'd like to upgrade these to the latest version: **Plesk 12.5.30**.

It is possible to upgrade via the control panel so it seems to be very easy.

What are the risks doing this upgrade myself? Should I do this myself or should I leave it to a sysadmin of the company where I rent these servers? In both cases the risks are mine but the difference is he has physical access which I have not.

How many (average) time will this upgrade take? 
Will there be downtime during the upgrade proces?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade plesk from your end. But I will suggest you please take a backup of your plesk databases and try to upgrade it through plesk panel. I think plesk upgrade process will take 20-25 min